# Cannot set the Order By to my SQL Statement, need a workaround

Tags: sql-server

I understand that I cannot have the SQL order by PaymentDate but my results come out not in Payment Date Order. Is there an easy way I can make sure the PERIOD column is in actual date order?

The SQL below works perfect its just if i add "--order by f.PaymentDate" I get 'Column "PaymentItem.PaymentDate" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.' So i'm trying to think how to get around this

```
            select g.SiteDescription,
                case a.Surname when '' then a.Company else a.Surname + ', ' + isnull(a.Forename,'') end as Landowner,
                h.PaymentTypeDesc as [RentalElection],
                d.RelevantProportion,@IN_showRelevantProportion as ShowRelevantProportion,
                g.SiteId,a.LandownerId,e.PaymentTypeId,e.PaymentCategoryId,     
                case @IN_OutputFormat 
                when 'Monthly' then 
                                    convert(char(3), f.PaymentDate, 0) + '-' + ltrim(Year(f.PaymentDate))
                when 'Annually' then
                                    ltrim(Year(f.PaymentDate)) 
                else 
                                    ltrim(Year(f.PaymentDate)) + ' Qtr ' + ltrim(datepart(quarter,f.PaymentDate))
                end as Period,
                sum(isnull(f.ActualPayment,0)) as Total
            from 
                [Site] g, 
                Landowner a,
                [Site] c,
                SiteAgreement d, 
                Payment e, 
                PaymentItem f,
                PaymentType h
                        where a.LandownerId = d.LandownerId 
                and g.SiteId = d.SiteId
                and e.SiteAgreementId = d.SiteAgreementId
                and f.PaymentId = e.PaymentId 
                and e.PaymentTypeId = h.PaymentTypeId
                and f.paymentdate between @IN_daysFrom and @IN_daysTo
                and isnull(f.ActualPayment,0) != 0

            group by g.SiteDescription,
                case a.Surname when '' then a.Company else a.Surname + ', ' + isnull(a.Forename,'') end,
                h.PaymentTypeDesc,
                d.RelevantProportion,
                g.SiteId,a.LandownerId,e.PaymentTypeId,e.PaymentCategoryId,
                case @IN_OutputFormat 
                when 'Monthly' then 
                        convert(char(3), f.PaymentDate, 0) + '-' + ltrim(Year(f.PaymentDate))
                when 'Annually' then
                        ltrim(Year(f.PaymentDate)) 
                else
                        ltrim(Year(f.PaymentDate)) + ' Qtr ' + ltrim(datepart(quarter,f.PaymentDate))
                end
            --order by f.PaymentDate
```

Comment: Ugh. Why are you using 1970s style joins (`FROM t1,t2,t3...`) and meaningless sequential aliases (`a,b,c...`)? If you're not returning any column that indicates payment date, how do you expect SQL Server to be able to order the results that way?

Comment: @AaronBertrand doesn't it do a cross join when you use the `FROM t1,t2,t3` syntax?

Comment: @Scotch: Not when you have the WHERE clause as it is here "simulating" a JOIN statement.

Comment: Aaron, you are repeating my question. I know I need to add payment date in order to make this work. The SQL works fine and performs well, just looking to add the order by

Answer (score 2):

Order by the entire expression that uses your Payment Date column:

```
ORDER BY case @IN_OutputFormat 
            when 'Monthly' then 
                    convert(char(3), f.PaymentDate, 0) + '-' + ltrim(Year(f.PaymentDate))
            when 'Annually' then
                    ltrim(Year(f.PaymentDate)) 
            else
                    ltrim(Year(f.PaymentDate)) + ' Qtr ' + ltrim(datepart(quarter,f.PaymentDate))
            end
```

Comment: To add to this, consider using a CTE and then SELECT from that, so you don't have to repeat the case statement in the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Good idea thanks, this compiles and runs, however i get the same order with monthly results, i.e. not date asc order. Perhaps I need to convert all values to date variables

Answer (score 0):

I got this going by just ordering at a string in format YYYY-MM. The MM needed left padded 0 of course:

CONVERT(CHAR(4), f.PaymentDate, 120) + ' ' + right('0'+ rtrim(ltrim(datepart(mm,f.PaymentDate))), 2)